# Hashing image names in emails?

Tags: email, html-email, spam, email-spam

Will hashing image names in my email cause any issues, for example with Spam Filters?

So instead of having `my-image.jpg` it would become something like `sdf8sa87f676sdf7sadf.jpg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should be no Problem.
Because spam filters search for special Words, special ip adresses and characteristic formating. Many websites use hashing links for e.g. Password reseting. For more information abut spam see: https://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/can-spam-act-compliance-guide-business

Answer (score 0):

Hashing image names will not be a problem as long as the images can be found on the server. I know this for a fact because MailChimp are hashing all the images we upload to their email editors.